# At risk of/from something

Tags: prepositions

I looked it up in the dictionary and it was given this example:

> Low-lying farmland may be at risk *from* flooding this weekend

It was also said that the use of *of* is generally allowed. So I was wondering whether or not

> Low-lying farmland may be at risk *of* flooding this weekend

would be marked as grammatically correct.

Comment: By whom would it be marked as incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both correct, but ***"at risk of"*** is actually a more common construction compared to ***"at risk from"***, see [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20risk%20of%2Cat%20risk%20from&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20risk%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20risk%20from%3B%2Cc0).

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at%20risk%20of%20flooding%2Cat%20risk%20from%20flooding&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20risk%20of%20flooding%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20risk%20from%20flooding%3B%2Cc0)***: "at risk of flooding", vs "at risk from flooding".

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been four years, but in my mind the two sentences are different.

"Low-lying farmland may be at risk from flooding this weekend" in my mind means there will be flooding and this will be risky for the low-lying farmland, which may end up destroyed.
"Low-lying farmland may be at risk of flooding this weekend" in my mind means that there is a risk the the low-lying farmland will be flooded.

In another example that is more current (2020)
"Older people are more at risk from getting the coronavirus." = If older people get the coronavirus, the risk for them is higher.
"Older people are more at risk of getting the coronavirus." = Older people are more likely to get the coronavirus.

Maybe this is just old-fashioned, since I was born in 1950 and languages change.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Thanks for writing up a great answer. Don't worry about answering old questions. There is a reason the answer box under old questions is always open to new answers (with exceptions). Sometimes late answers can be better answers.